# For each loop not skipping items

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, foreach

I have a for each loop in vb.net for this particular example there are 2 items in list but after the first item the loop exits are there errors in the code

```
Public Function findUserID(ByVal list As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String)), ByVal value As String)
    Dim id As String = String.Empty
    For Each kvp  In list
        If (kvp.Value = value) Then
            id = kvp.Key
        End If
    Next
    Return id
End Function
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question, and tell us what exception you're getting, or what result is coming back versus what you expect?

Comment: Need to provide some more information here, what is `kvp.value` includes?

Comment: There is no exception, right now it cycles through the first kvp and then returns an empty string, it dies not attempt to check the second value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
dim kvp as KeyValuePair
kvp = list.Find(p=>p.Value = value))
if kvp = null then return "" else return kvp.Key
```

One user told me to modify it in this way:

```
dim kvp = list.Find(Function(e) e.Value = value)
If kvp Is Nothing Then Return "" Else Return kvp.Key
```

Sorry if this code has some error, but I cannot try and I usually write in C#.
So my code (in C#) would be:

```
KeyValuePair kvp = list.Find(p=>p.Value == value));
return kvp == null ? "" : kvp.Key;
```

Comment: I have not solved the issue, the second block of code runs fine but did not return a result

Comment: @user936233: are you really sure that data contained in your list is correct? Code is correct, so if result is empty probably there should be an error before...

Comment: Turns out the data in the list contained extra spaces, I guess since there were only two resuld the code could evaluete both without having to go through the for each loop again

Comment: This code is better and seems more efficient, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Why you have the id variable and don't return the Key directly if you found a valid?
So the collection will loop through all KeyValuePairs and not stop on any results.

```
Public Function FindUserID(ByVal list As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String)), ByVal value As String)
    For Each kvp In list
        If (kvp.Value = value) Then
            Return kvp.Key
        End If
     Next
End Function
```

But thats not the error, did you debug the method and verified that there are more than one KeyValuePairs in the list?

Comment: yes the debugger verified that there is more than one KeyValuePairs in the list