# VB.NET For Each Loop exits after one iteration

Tags: vb.net

I have a For Each loop that is only iterating 1 element.  It begins with the 6th element out of 32 in my test, and happens to be one where the comp.includeMe evaluates to True.  After the outer if statement is executed, it begins the 2nd iteration but exits the loop and returns immediately after the comp.includeMe evaluated to false.  No errors or warnings are present, and I have verified that there are elements in the components object.  Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong, and why this syntax doesn't work?

```
Public Class BOM    
    Public Property components as New List(Of Component)

    Public Function TotalArea(ByVal adjusted As Boolean) As Double
        Dim total As Double = 0
        For Each comp As Component In components
            If comp.includeMe = True Then
                If adjusted Then
                    total += comp.GetAdjustedSize() * comp.quantity
                Else
                    total += comp.area * comp.quantity
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Return total
    End Function

    public sub Add(byval comp as Component)

        components.add(comp)
    end sub
End Class

Public Class Component
    Public Property quantity as Integer
    Public Property area as Double
    Public Property includeMe as Boolean

    ...
End Class

' object construction
Dim bomlist as New BOM
bomlist.add(comp)
```

Comment: Where do you initialize `components`?

Comment: when the BOM class is constructed a list is passed in

Comment: I've verified that there are actually values in components with the debugger.  None are missing

Comment: Syntax looks perfect if I'm understanding your question.... according to this code, for every component in `Components` where `.includeme = true`, it'll enter the if and append onto `total` accordingly depending on the value of `adjusted`. IF `.includeme = False`, then it skips that component and doesn;t add to total at all.... Is that what you want to have happen??? Can you provide information about what you're looking to have happen exactly??

Comment: you do only want to compute the `includeMe = true` items right? Can you give an example of your input?

Comment: Yes @JohnBustos that's what I'm looking for this to do.  If includeMe is set to true then I want to total that area.  There are two types of area, which is where the adjusted bool comes in

Comment: That being the case, can you provide your code where you fill your components list / what happens when you step through the code in debug mode?? What happens with the first 5 components?? This SHOULD be quick to figure out with debugging....

Comment: I found a similar post I think, but there wasn't much resolution on why this is actually happening.  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357854/for-each-loop-not-skipping-items)

Comment: I have used code similar to this hundreds of times before and it works... there must be a small glitch somewhere....

Comment: I added in a small snippet to my answer.  I'm banging my head against the wall on this one.  I've done this tons of times as well.

Comment: Probably won't make a difference, but with properties declared the way you have, try using `_components` every time you reference them within the BOM class... MIGHT make a difference, even though I doubt it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging a little deeper, it seems that the foreach statement is recognizing the first if statement and pulls values only if it is true.  I realized I only had only had one component with the includeMe Boolean set to true.  After I set other components to true as well, I observed that the For Each iterates exactly the number of times as the number of components with includeMe = True

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding some debug statements to assist with debugging:

```
Public Class BOM    
    Public Property components as New List(Of Component)

    Public Function TotalArea(ByVal adjusted As Boolean) As Double
        Dim total As Double = 0
        Debug.Print(components.Count)
        For Each comp As Component In components
            Debug.Print(comp.includeMe)  
            If comp.includeMe = True Then
                If adjusted Then
                    total += comp.GetAdjustedSize() * comp.quantity
                Else
                    total += comp.area * comp.quantity
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Return total
    End Function

    public sub Add(byval comp as Component)

        components.add(comp)
    end sub
End Class
```